# How do I reset URL for Product Display when replacing the main product? (instead of having an increment added to the URL)

Tags: commerce, path-aliases

I am having trouble with URLs after replacing items by a delete/re-import. The site uses Pathauto module.

I am adding content to a Drupal Commerce site using Feeds. I had uploaded the Product Variations and then Product Display for one product type. I realized that there were several mistakes with the CSV file and decided to start from scratch.

I deleted the original products by going to Products > Manage Products. From the "List" tab, I selected all of the products and chose "Bulk Action" >> "Delete". The products were deleted from the website, but the URL was incremented by a "-0" and the original now returned a "404" error.

Desired: `www.XYZ.com/product/widget`

vs.

Less than desired: `www.XYZ.com/product/widget-0`

How do I return the Product Display to the "widget" URL without the "-0"?

If I try to override it by manually making the update on the Product Display, I get an error message that indicates that URL is already taken.

I would like to clean this up for SEO. Please advise.

Thanks,
keb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure why this happens in Commerce Kickstart, while it does not happen with regular Drupal. Almost as if the product's path are cached or something, but clearing all caches after deleting a product did not change the outcome. But I did find an easy solution.

You can fix that by deleting your Aliases, go to `/admin/config/search/path/delete_bulk`

[image]

And then regenerating them

[image]

Comment: Thanks @No-Sssweat for the recommendation. I had looked in URL Config and really didn't want to pull the trigger there. It sounds like I need to do this following Feeds Imports if we have deleted and later replaced an item on import.

Comment: Confirmed: This works. Not sure that this is a good long term solutions for Drupal Commerce though. Seems like it would be prone to error and potentially impact SEO.